# Trying to get specific values from a custom made drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom select menu(I just wanted to see if I could do it) and I'm having some issues.  When the user clicks on the box, I want the user to be able to select an option and have it show up in that particular box.  The problem I'm having is that the selected text shows up in each box, regardless of which menu they're selecting from.  How do I fix this?

Here's my pen.

http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/LIKsJ

**select**

```
<body>
    <div class="select">
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">Hello</div>
            <div class="option">Goodbye</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select">
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option active">A</div>
            <div class="option">B</div>
            <div class="option">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $(".select");
    $(select).on("click", function(){
        $(this).find(".option-menu").each(function(){
            $(this).toggle();
        })

        $(".option").on("click", function(){
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(select).children("p").remove();
            var option = $(this).text();
            console.log(option);
            $(select).prepend("<p>" +option +"<p>");
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on some option yo are refering to the variable `select`

> var select = $(".select");

That calls all the elements with class `select`, you nedd to make more specific the selector. Try adding this line:

```
$(select).on("click", function(){
    select = $(this); //ADD THIS
    $(this).find(".option-menu").each(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
})
```

Check the Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaemF

Answer (score 0):

You have to use specific container div

```
<div class="container1">
     <div class="select">
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">Hello</div>
            <div class="option">Goodbye</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var select = $(".container1 .select");
    $(select).on("click", function(){
        $(this).find(".option-menu").each(function(){
            $(this).toggle();
        })

        $(".container1 .option").on("click", function(){
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(select).children("p").remove();
            var option = $(this).text();
            console.log(option);
            $(select).prepend("<p>" +option +"<p>");
        })
    })
```

Your problem is you are using same classes for 2 elements.
If I were you, I write this kind of code as jquery plugin.

// With plugin you can create your code with one line of code.
$('#container').createSelectMenu();

Comment: I would like to make this a plugin, but I haven't got the slightest clue as to how.  Perhaps I should research it.